# How to pay using Stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a stripe app with some subscription plans. I created a subscription for user by following code.

```
 var subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: user.stripe_account_id,
        items: [{ price: plan.plan_id }], // Replace with the actual price ID
      });
```

I am confused about this subscription process and payment of subscription . Should I initiate the payment for this customer after creating subscription (like above code ) ?

I tried to look up codes to process the payment from API (nestjs/node) , but the tutorials are mostly showing how to do payment for a subscription from stripe dash board.

My questions are :

**1. How to make payment for this customer from my API (node)?.**

**2. When this plan ends (eg: 30 day plan ) , How to re subscribe for this user for the same plan ? And how to make payment for this customer for re subscription ?**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read and follow the guide. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

1/ After creating the subscription, you can use the PaymentIntent for the first upcoming payment (`latest_invoice.payment_intent`), you use that on the frontend with Stripe Elements to accept card details and process the payment.

2/ That just happens by default, you don't have to do anything else(that's what a Subscription in Stripe is, it charges the customer on the period you specify when you create the Price(which defines the amount and the billing period).

Highly suggest reading Stripe's docs and following the guides.

Answer (score -2):

Certainly! Here's an example code snippet in Node.js to create a subscription for a customer and handle the payment:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

async function createSubscription(customerId, priceId) {
  try {
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customerId,
      items: [{ price: priceId }],
    });
    console.log('Subscription created:', subscription);
    // Subscription created successfully, payment will be automatically handled by Stripe
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating subscription:', error);
    // Handle the error appropriately
  }
}

// Usage example
const customerId = 'CUSTOMER_ID'; // Replace with the customer ID from your database
const priceId = 'PRICE_ID'; // Replace with the price ID of the subscription plan

createSubscription(customerId, priceId);
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer?